# Partial differentiation, solving an equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have this question about partial differentiation which I try to solve but I seem to get wrong all the time.

The question is: if $x=t\sin(s)$ and $y=t\cos(s)$, find $d^2f(x,y)/dsdt$.

I'm assuming that what I have to do is take $df/ds\cdot df/dt$, not much more than that, which should be:

$$df/ds=t\cos(s)f_1-t\sin(s)f_2$$
$$df/dt=\sin(s)f_1+\cos(s)f_2$$

and then $d^2f/dsdt$ should be after I've simplified it: $$t\cos(s)\sin(s)f_{11}+t\cos(s)^2f_{12}-t\sin(s)^2f_{12}-t\sin(s)\cos(s)f_{22}$$

But the answer is according to the book: $$\cos(s)f_1-\sin(s)f_2+t\sin(s)\cos(s)(f_{11}-f_{22})+t(\cos(s)^2-\sin(s)^2)f_{12}$$

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $ \ \frac{d^2f}{ds \ dt } \ $ is _not_ a product of two first partial derivatives, but rather $ \ \frac{d}{ds} \ \left(\frac{df}{dt} \ \right) \ $ .

Comment: Okay, what about d^2f/dt^2, is that df/dt*df/dt or is that also how you wrote it? and how does one calculate that what you wrote?

Comment: It is the derivative of a derivative, just as is the case for higher derivatives of functions of a single variable.  You take the first derivative function and differentiate that with respect to the indicated variable to get the appropriate second derivative.  A product of derivatives would be notated _as_ $ \ \left( \ \frac{df}{ds} \ \right)  \left( \ \frac{df}{dt} \ \right) \ $ , which is not what is called for here.

Comment: Thanks, but I simply can't seem to solve an equation like that, could you give me an example of how to do it?

Comment: I follow as far as to d/ds(sin(s)f1+cos(s)f2) but I'm not sure what to do here or how to derivative his function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see where you messed up.
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}t\cos s-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}t\sin s$$
So
$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial s\partial t}=\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)t\cos s+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(t\cos s\right)-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\right)t\sin s-\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\left(t\sin s\right)$$
And you were forgetting about the second and fourth terms in the above expression.